# Trouble parsing string to GregoriamCalendar type for use in ArrayList

Tags: java, parsing, csv, arraylist, gregorian-calendar

so I'm having some trouble here - I am trying to create a class to download historical stock market data from yahoo. Basically, at line 64 I need to parse a string of the form yyyy-MM-dd, to a GregorianCalendar type. I have been trying for a while now and looking at other solutions on here and elsewhere - while I can parse the string to Gregorian Calendar, I can't get it to add to the ArrayList dates in the same form yyyy-MM-dd. I am using .split(,) to split each line of the csv into separate elements, and all other types are Doubles and Ints which is easy enough.

line returns a string such as:
 2015-11-12,116.260002,116.82,115.650002,115.720001,32262600,115.720001

Thanks in advance!

```
    public StockDownloader(String symbol, GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end) { 
        dates = new ArrayList<GregorianCalendar>(); 
        opens = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
        highs = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
        lows = new ArrayList<Double>();
        closes = new ArrayList<Double>();
        volumes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        adjCloses = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

        //deconstructed URL
        String url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s="+symbol+
                "&a="+start.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
                "&b="+start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
                "&c="+start.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
                "&d="+end.get(Calendar.MONTH)+
                "&e="+end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+
                "&f="+end.get(Calendar.YEAR)+
                "&g=d&ignore=.csv";

        try { 
            URL yhoofin = new URL(url); //creates URL from String url
            URLConnection data = yhoofin.openConnection(); //invokes openConnection method on URL
            Scanner input = new Scanner(data.getInputStream()); //Returns an input stream that reads from this open connection.
            if(input.hasNext()) //skip line, it's just the header
                input.nextLine(); //advances to next line

            //start reading data
            while(input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();

                String[] splitLine = line.split(","); 

>>Problem here  //dates.add( add the date );
                opens.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[OPEN]));
                highs.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[HIGH]));
                lows.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[LOW]));
                closes.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[CLOSE]));
                volumes.add(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[VOLUME]));
                adjCloses.add(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[ADJCLOSE]));


            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { //catch any error (exception) that happens
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using GregorianCalendar instances to hold dates?

Comment: I'm very new to Java, so I'm not sure - if you can suggest a better method please do :)

Answer (score 2):

You should store dates in list not as GregorianCalendar but as Dates:

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>()
```

Then you can parse dates with SimpleDateFormat:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
...
dates.add(format.parse(splitLine[0]));
```

SimpleDateFormat may help you to format date to string back, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH"); //another format
String formattedDate = newFormat.format(date); //14-11-2015 11
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: When constructing the URL, how do I then each element (what is now Calendar.Month, etc....)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your question. How do you then each element what? I've edited my answer, maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to process this for you. It's going to be faster as the input stream is processed in a separate thread and your code will be easier to maintain:

```
public StockDownload(String symbol, GregorianCalendar start, GregorianCalendar end) {
    //deconstructed URL
    String url = "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=" + symbol +
            "&a=" + start.get(Calendar.MONTH) +
            "&b=" + start.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
            "&c=" + start.get(Calendar.YEAR) +
            "&d=" + end.get(Calendar.MONTH) +
            "&e=" + end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) +
            "&f=" + end.get(Calendar.YEAR) +
            "&g=d&ignore=.csv";

    //Csv parser configuration - many options here, check the tutorial
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    //there's headers in the input, let's use them
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

    //You want the data split into columns, so let's use a column processor for that
    ObjectColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new ObjectColumnProcessor();
    //here we assign a conversion to the fields you are interested in getting.
    columnProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.toCalendar("yyyy-mm-dd")).add("Date");
    columnProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.toDouble()).add("Open","High","Low","Close","Adj Close");
    columnProcessor.convertFields(Conversions.toInteger()).add("Volume");

    //Let's tell the parser to submit all parsed rows to the column processor.
    settings.setRowProcessor(columnProcessor);
    //Creates a CSV parser with our configuration
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    try {
        URL yhoofin = new URL(url); //creates URL from String url
        URLConnection data = yhoofin.openConnection(); //invokes openConnection method on URL

        //opens the connection and parses everything. All rows are sent to the the column processor.
        parser.parseAll(new InputStreamReader(data.getInputStream()));
    } catch (Exception e) { //catch any error (exception) that happens
        System.err.println(e);
    }

    //Parsing is done. Let's just get the values.
    Map<String, List<Object>> columns = columnProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();

    //Each header in the input is a key in the map. Here we get the list of values for the "close" column.
    System.out.println(columns.get("Close"));
}
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).